# How to move reivew block after related product in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, review, related-products

How to move related product block before product review block on product details page. i will try some code but no luck with this. i want to move related product block in to tab panel or review block at the last of the content in magento 2.

Comment: product reviews ? where these are occurring in page now ?

Comment: try this    <move element="reviews.tab" destination="main.content" after="-"/>      in after name of block after which you want to place them. currently they are at the end of page.

Comment: can I post as answer ?

Answer (score 3):

Go To you theme Directory

> app/design/frontend///Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product-info-main" before="product.info.review"/>


    </body>    
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to move review block after related product on product detail page.
> Go to **catalog_product_view.xml** file

```
<move element="reviews.tab" destination="content.aside"  after="catalog.product.related"/>
```

> This will move review block after related product.